# Retrieve recent 5 days forecast for each cities with latest issue date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to retrieve the recent 5 days forecast info for each cities.

My table looks like below

[image]

The real problem is with the issue date.

the city may contain several forecast info for the same date with distinct issue date.

I need to retrieve recent 5 records for each cities with latest issue date and group by forecast date

I have tried something like below but not giving the expected result

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CITY_ID ORDER BY FORECAST_DATE DESC, ISSUE_DATE DESC) AS rn,
    CITY_ID, FORECAST_DATE, ISSUE_DATE
FROM 
    FORECAST    
GROUP BY FORECAST_DATE
) WHERE rn <= 5
```

[image]

Any suggestion or advice will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the latest issued forecast per day over the most recent 5 days for each city:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT f.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY city_id ORDER BY forecast_date DESC )
           AS forecast_rank,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY city_id, forecast_date ORDER BY issue_date DESC )
           AS issue_rn
  FROM   Forecast f
)
WHERE  forecast_rank <= 5
AND    issue_rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Partition by` works like `group by` but for the function only.

Try

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*,
       row_number() over (partition by city_id, forecast_date order by issue_date desc) as r_ord
from Forecast
)
select CTE.*
from CTE
where r_ord <= 5
```

Comment: not working as expected, See in your solution it groups by forecast_date, city_id hence r_ord <= 5 will return records for the same date, same city

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CITY_ID, FORECAST_DATE order by ISSUE_DATE DESC) AS rn,
        CITY_ID, FORECAST_DATE, ISSUE_DATE
    FROM 
        FORECAST    
    ) WHERE rn <= 5
```

Comment: This will get the first 5 issued forecasts each day with no limit on the number of days. Not what the OP wanted.